# how to get previous page URL, different domain name using javascript

Tags: javascript, cross-browser

Is it possible to get the url of the previous website page from another website domain using javascript, example:
user have this website url in browser:

`www.example.com/page1.html`

then user cleared the browser address bar and wrote my website

`url: www.test.com`

What I need is using javascript to get the

`www.example.com/page1.html url.`

Is that possible?

Comment: This is a breach of privacy. Why do you need to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, for the same reasons you can not get the url from an iframe if it's on a different domain: cross-domain security.

What you can do is get the `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` in php but it's not always set... 
Or as @FabrícioMatté commented `document.referrer` in javascript, but reliability is just as bad.

> The address of the page (if any) which referred the user agent to the current page. This is set by the user agent. Not all user agents will set this, and some provide the ability to modify HTTP_REFERER as a feature. In short, it cannot really be trusted.

http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php

To go back to the previous page you can use `history.go(-1)` in javascript.

Comment: `document.referrer` is the JS equivalent of PHP's `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']`.